# What's the buildout:zcml option for?

Tags: plone, buildout, zcml

In one of my projects' buildout.cfg files I have something like this:

```
[buildout]
...
zcml =
    my.package
    plone.reload
...
```

Everything works fine but I'm still puzzled about what's the reason some packages do need to be listed here and why others don't.

What's the purpose of it to begin with?

While doing some research I end up on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munin.zope/2.1 which says that *if you use z3c.autoinclude and plone (+3.3) you don't need it*.

Does that mean that if a distribution has the z3c.autoinclude slug on its `setup.py`, i.e.

```
entry_points="""
# -*- Entry points: -*-
[z3c.autoinclude.plugin]
target = plone
""",
```

you don't have to care about `buildout:zcml`?

Comment: Exactly, All packages you're using should have the `z3c.autoinclude slug`, so loading the zcml manually is not necessary. btw: I never defined  `zcml` in buildout part like eggs.

Comment: BTW, the autoinclusion saves time at first hand, but there's also critical voices around, pointing out that "Explicit is better than implicit". See G. Chapelle: http://bubblenet.be/blog/lets-get-rid-of-z3c.autoinclude and D. J. Beitey:http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/07/plone-overrides-zcml-gets-auto-included-with-z3c-autoinclude/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no inherent functionality** related to the `zcml` parameter in the [buildout] section, other than a convenient place to define `zcml`.

Typically an [instance] section will refer to it:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
eggs = Plone
zcml = ${buildout:zcml}
```

[The use of `buildout:zcml` similar to `buildout:eggs` is an anti-pattern, IMO](http://blog.aclark.net/2012/10/20/review-of-aspelis-professional-plone-4-development/#what-i-like)

Answer (score 1):

In buildout config files, `name=value` can be used in two ways:

- to specify a value for a name that has predefined functionality
- to assign a name to a value to avoid copy and paste.

`buildout:zcml` is an example of the second case.

In other words, the only reason to use `buildout:zcml` would be the need to use its value in various places.

However, when I need to reuse `zcml`, I rather define it in a `plone.recipe.zope2instance` part. And reuse that value in another part.